# List Comprehensions (Transitiv)

Tags: python, list, function, list-comprehension, any

I need to write a Python function isReflexive and isSymmetric, which are exclusive from Python's List Comprehensions and the all or any function.
Example:

```
isSymmetric([2,3,4],[(2,3),(3,2),(3,3),(2,4),(4,2)])
True

isTransitive([[2,3,4,5],[(2,3),(3,2),(3,3),(3,4),(2,4),(4,2),(2,2),(4,4),(4,3)]
```

True

The 1 argument is a base set (list) and the 2 argument is a relation over this base set.

I tried this, but this doesnt work, because I also check tuples that I don't have to check:

```
def isSymmetric(g,r):
    return all([(x,y) = r for x in g for y in g])
```

I don't know how to sovle the problem...
And isTransitiv I don't know how to start D:

Thanks in advance for all the help!

Comment: Have you consulted your textbook, teacher, etc. first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following comp/gen based implementations will work for symmetry and transitivity:

```
from itertools import product

def isSymmetric(g, r):
    s = set(r)
    return all(x[::-1] in s for x in s)

def isTransitive(g, r):
    s = set(r)
    return all(
       ((x,y) in s and (y,z) in s) <= ((x,z) in s) 
       for x, y, z in product(g, repeat=3)
    )
```

Both are not ideal from an algorithmic POV. Better (less and faster checks) would be:

```
def isSymmetric(g, r):
    s = set(r)
    while s:
        x, y = s.pop()
        if x != y:  # (x, x) does not need a partner
            try:
                s.remove((y, x))
            except KeyError:  # reverse not there!
                return False
    return True
```

The transitivity check is a bit more complicated. You can use an auxiliary data structure (`collections.defaultdict`) to make all the checks constant  instead of linear:

```
def isTransitive(g, r):
    d = defaultdict(set)
    for x, y in r:
        d[x].add(y)
    for x in g:  # `for x in d` reduces iterations in the general case
        for y in d[x]:  # all (x, y)
            if not all(z in d[x] for z in d[y]):  # exists (x, z) for (y, z)?
                return False
    return True
```

Comment: I know what transitivity and symmertry is, but I want to do the function only with list comprehensions and any or all. I already tried it without any or all and list comprehensions. I know how this works but I want to know it works with list comprehensions .....

Comment: Why a comprehension if you can have a generator that does the same without the memory footprint?

Comment: That really should be `return all((x,x) in r for x in g)`

Comment: I know that it works with list comprehensions, but I don't know how to programm it. I already programmed reflexiv... and now I want to programm transititv and symmetric

Comment: The first one is what seek for symmetry, isn't it?

Comment: I added the comp/gen based variants. Note though that the transitivity check in particular will deteriorate quickly for larger domains and relations.

Comment: Yes, but shouldn't it read like this if I only want to use list comprehensions? `def isSymmetric(g, r):
    return all(x[::-1] in set(r) for x in set(r))`

Comment: If "only comprehension" is that narrow that you are willing to introduce all kinds of terrible anti-patterns (creating the set over and over and over...). Then it's actually better not to use a set at all: `return all(x[::-1] in r for x in r)`

Comment: Sorry for so many questions. I'm teaching myself Python and on one website these tasks were without solutions and I want to find out how it works. What you have written has helped me. Thank you very much. Only the function with isTransitive is a bit difficult for me to understand.

Comment: You probably mean the part `a in s and b in s <= c in s` part. We know from statement logic that "if a ^ b then  c" is only untrue if "a^b" is true and "c" is false. In Python bools, that one case would be  `a and b > c` since `True > False` (`1 > 0`). So it holds if `a and b <= c` ;-)